# Magento 2 Send email of order place from observer ?

Tags: magento2, event-observer, email

Event is : **checkout_onepage_controller_success_action**

How can I send email to Same Customer again who placed order from observer?

Observer:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds(); 
    if (count($orderIds)) {
        $orderId = $orderIds[0];            
        $order = $this->_orderFactory->create()->load($orderId); 
    }
}
```

Comment: found my answer

Comment: You should answer your question if you found answer yourself that will help other people. So please answer.

Comment: Yes, definitely buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added following code in my observer:

Use:
    use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender;

Declare variable in class:

```
protected $orderSender;
```

In constructor:

```
$this->orderSender = $orderSender;
```

In execute:

```
try {
         $this->orderSender->send($order);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
         $this->logger->critical($e);
    }
```

It sends mail 2nd time to customer because customer already receives mail after order place.

In my module their is perticular need for that, So I'm using that.